# how to stop/remove a container which was run with "sleep 1d" command?

Tags: docker, containers

how to stop/remove a container which was run with "sleep 1d" command?

```
docker container ls
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE           COMMAND      CREATED         STATUS         PORTS     NAMES
6f58b0bcd9ad   alpine:latest   "sleep 1d"   9 seconds ago   Up 4 seconds             pinger.1.oq6ebiyxuz2khbz4ktvism7qs
f7343335e098   alpine:latest   "sleep 1d"   4 minutes ago   Up 4 minutes             pinger.2.yub91n5yq05ahn8un0t91bro6
```

Ive been trying rm, stop, kill, but it always gets re-generated :(

Answer (score 0):

You started the container using swarm mode, so swarm mode is recreating the container. Delete the managing service to delete the containers:

```
docker service rm pinger
```